# Sum of terms after partial fraction decomposition

Tags: approximation-theory, fractions

I am facing the following problem (all $a_i$ being positive and all different)
$$F=\int_0^1 \,dx\prod_{i=1}^n  \frac 1{x+a_i}=\int_0^1\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {A_i}{x+a_i}\,dx=\sum_{i=1}^n A_i \log \left(1+\frac{1}{a_i}\right)$$

The $a_i$ being large
$$F=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{ A_i}{a_i}+ O\left(\frac{1}{a_i^2}\right)$$

**Is there a formal way to express this summation as a function of the $a_i$ ?**

Comment: The problem is simple if the $a_i$'s are in AP or GP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be silently assumed that all $a_i$ are pairwise distinct.

Let $f(x):=\prod_{i=1}^n (x+a_i)$. Then $A_i = \frac1{f'(-a_i)}$.